# Running multiple Javascript on one page, all work individually but when together only last will run

Tags: javascript, function, random, generator

I have a simple film review site and on one of its pages wanted to include a bunch of random generators. They include: Random actor, Random actress, Random year and Random genre. Each code itself works fine, but when I place them together on the same page the last one written always overrides the others. I realize that I must need to do something to differentiate between the scripts but I am very new at this and am a bit of a loss. Below is the code I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
msg=new Array();
msg[0]='Chester Morris';
msg[1]='Wallace Beery';
msg[2]='Ronald Colman';
msg[3]='Maurice Chevalier';
msg[4]='Lionel Barrymore';
msg[5]='Lawrence Ribbett';
msg[6]='Jackie Cooper';
msg[7]='Fredric March';
msg[8]='Charles Laughton';
msg[9]='Leslie Howard';
msg[10]='Paul Muni';
msg[11]='Clark Gable';
function random(){
i=Math.floor(msg.length*Math.random());
alert(msg[i]);}
//--></script>
<INPUT type="button" value="Random Actor" name="actorbutton" onClick='random()'>

<script type="text/javascript">
msg=new Array();
msg[0]='Jean Harlow';
msg[1]='Greta Garbo';
msg[2]='Bette Davis';
msg[3]='Joan Blondell';
msg[4]='Myrna Loy';
msg[5]='Janet Gaynor';
msg[6]='Louise Dresser';
msg[7]='Gloria Swanson';
msg[8]='Mary Pickford';
msg[9]='Ruth Chatterton';
function random(){
i=Math.floor(msg.length*Math.random());
alert(msg[i]);}
</script>
<INPUT type="button" value="Random Actress" name="actressbutton" onClick='random()'>

<script type="text/javascript">
msg=new Array();
msg[0]='1910';
msg[1]='1911';
msg[2]='1912';
msg[3]='1913';
msg[4]='1914';
msg[5]='1915';
msg[6]='1916';
msg[7]='1917';
msg[8]='1918';
msg[9]='1919';
function random(){
i=Math.floor(msg.length*Math.random());
alert(msg[i]);}
</script>
<INPUT type="button" value="Random Year" name="yearbutton" onClick='random()'>

<script type="text/javascript">
msg=new Array();
msg[0]='Action';
msg[1]='Adventure';
msg[2]='Biographical';
msg[3]='Comedy (parody)';
msg[4]='Comedy (screwball)';
msg[5]='Comedy (slapstick)';
msg[6]='Drama';
msg[7]='Melodrama';
msg[8]='Historical drama';
msg[9]='Epic';
msg[10]='Fantasy';
msg[11]='Film noir';
msg[12]='Horror';
msg[13]='Musical';
msg[14]='Mystery';
function random(){
i=Math.floor(msg.length*Math.random());
alert(msg[i]);}
//--></script>
<INPUT type="button" value="Random Genre" name="genrebutton" onClick='random()'>
```

Comment: Name your functions different things, problem solved!

Comment: and your msg variable too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define different things with the same name (the variable `msg` and the function `random`), the later ones will override the earlier ones (and so only leave the latest ones).

You should rename the variables and functions according to their purpose (`actorMsg`, `randomActor`, `actressList`, `randomActress`, etc.)